# Erro mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Estou tentando fazer uma base de dados para um projeto academico, estou fazendo o model no workbench e depois tento sincronizar com o phpmyadmin, acontece que ao fazer as foreign keys acontece sempre o mesmo erro, mas nao consigo perceber que erro é este, é bem especifico, dai ter procurado no google e nao ter encontrado solução.

Erro:

> ```
> Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,   CONSTRAINT `fk_users_bookRegistration1`
>     FOREIGN KEY (`bookRegistr' at line 11 SQL Code:
>         CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libraryRat`.`users` (
>           `userID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>           `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>           `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>           `password` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>           `birthdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>           `booksReaden` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>           `wishList` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>           `bookRegistration_userID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
>           PRIMARY KEY (`userID`),
>           INDEX `fk_users_bookRegistration1_idx` (`bookRegistration_userID` ASC) VISIBLE,
>           CONSTRAINT `fk_users_bookRegistration1`
>             FOREIGN KEY (`bookRegistration_userID`)
>             REFERENCES `libraryRat`.`bookRegistration` (`userID`)
>             ON DELETE NO ACTION
>             ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
>         ENGINE = InnoDB
>         DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
>
> SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed
> Fetching back view definitions in final form. Nothing to fetch
> ```

Código mysql:

```
   -- MySQL Workbench Synchronization
-- Generated: 2018-12-31 01:55
-- Model: New Model
-- Version: 1.0
-- Project: Name of the project
-- Author: nelson

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libraryRat`.`users` (
  `userID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `booksReaden` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `wishList` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `bookRegistration_userID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`),
  INDEX `fk_users_bookRegistration_idx` (`bookRegistration_userID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_bookRegistration`
    FOREIGN KEY (`bookRegistration_userID`)
    REFERENCES `libraryRat`.`bookRegistration` (`userID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libraryRat`.`books` (
  `bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `isbn` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cover` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` DECIMAL(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `genres` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libraryRat`.`author` (
  `authorID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `about` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`authorID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libraryRat`.`admin` (
  `idAdmin` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `approvals` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `bookApprovals_adminID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAdmin`),
  INDEX `fk_admin_bookApprovals1_idx` (`bookApprovals_adminID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_admin_bookApprovals1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`bookApprovals_adminID`)
    REFERENCES `libraryRat`.`bookApprovals` (`adminID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libraryRat`.`ratings` (
  `ratingID` DECIMAL(50) NOT NULL,
  `bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ratingID`, `bookID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libraryRat`.`bookRegistration` (
  `userID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorID` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `genres` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `books_bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`, `bookID`),
  INDEX `fk_bookRegistration_books1_idx` (`books_bookID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bookRegistration_books1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`books_bookID`)
    REFERENCES `libraryRat`.`books` (`bookID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libraryRat`.`bookApprovals` (
  `adminID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `bookID` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorID` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `genres` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `userID` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `bookRegistration_userID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`adminID`),
  INDEX `fk_bookApprovals_bookRegistration1_idx` (`bookRegistration_userID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bookApprovals_bookRegistration1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`bookRegistration_userID`)
    REFERENCES `libraryRat`.`bookRegistration` (`userID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libraryRat`.`books_has_ratings` (
  `books_bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `ratings_ratingID` DECIMAL(50) NOT NULL,
  `ratings_bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`books_bookID`, `ratings_ratingID`, `ratings_bookID`),
  INDEX `fk_books_has_ratings_ratings1_idx` (`ratings_ratingID` ASC, `ratings_bookID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_books_has_ratings_books_idx` (`books_bookID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_books_has_ratings_books`
    FOREIGN KEY (`books_bookID`)
    REFERENCES `libraryRat`.`books` (`bookID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_books_has_ratings_ratings1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ratings_ratingID` , `ratings_bookID`)
    REFERENCES `libraryRat`.`ratings` (`ratingID` , `bookID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libraryRat`.`users_has_ratings` (
  `users_userID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `ratings_ratingID` DECIMAL(50) NOT NULL,
  `ratings_bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`users_userID`, `ratings_ratingID`, `ratings_bookID`),
  INDEX `fk_users_has_ratings_ratings1_idx` (`ratings_ratingID` ASC, `ratings_bookID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_users_has_ratings_users1_idx` (`users_userID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_has_ratings_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_userID`)
    REFERENCES `libraryRat`.`users` (`userID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_has_ratings_ratings1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ratings_ratingID` , `ratings_bookID`)
    REFERENCES `libraryRat`.`ratings` (`ratingID` , `bookID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `libraryRat`.`author_has_books` (
  `author_authorID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `books_bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`author_authorID`, `books_bookID`),
  INDEX `fk_author_has_books_books1_idx` (`books_bookID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_author_has_books_author1_idx` (`author_authorID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_author_has_books_author1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`author_authorID`)
    REFERENCES `libraryRat`.`author` (`authorID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_author_has_books_books1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`books_bookID`)
    REFERENCES `libraryRat`.`books` (`bookID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Obrigado pessoal!

Comment: Como já respondido, esse VISIBLE não faz parte da sintaxe do DB usado. Como diz a mensagem de erro, você tem um erro de SINTAXE  e sugere olhar o manual da versão do MariaDB utilizado. Importante quando for assim, postar a versão do DB na pergunta e preferencialmente destacar a parte relevante da mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde,

O problema é que o seu script está na na versão 8 e seu banco está em uma versão inferior a do script 
[veja nesse link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92269)

Você pode está vendo a versão de modelagem do banco em Model > Model Options > MySQL

Você pode está removendo as "VISIBLE", por padrão ele já vem habilitado.